# Adafruit GPS module (plugged in via SMA to u.FL adapter to usb) is preventing all of my other USB devices from working

Tags: usb, gps

I just got the Adafruit GPS breakout kit. I've also purchased Adafruit's SMA to u.FL adapter to allow me to just plug it into my USB port. However, whenever I do, it prevents all of my other usb connected devices from working, including the wifi dongle. The moment I plug it in, the light on the wifi dongle goes off. Also, when I plug it in, the red light on the board starts flashing instead of glowing solid red. This may be all the diagnostic inform you guys need to fix this but here is a photo of the wiring from the adapter to the module.

[image]

Wired using these instructions on https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-on-the-raspberry-pi/setting-everything-up

[image]

I find it odd that there's no cable going into 3.3V on the gps board, but the instructions don't seem to tell me to do that.

Thanks

UPDATE: I tried plugging this guy into my computer's USB port and got this error message:

[image]

So I'm drawing too much power somehow. Not sure what exactly that means or how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried a different power supply or a powered USB hub? Also, if you look at the board the 3.3V is out not in.

Comment: So my macbook's usb ports are definitely powered, and I got an error message "USB Devices Disabled -- Unplug the device using too much power to re-enable USB devices." Will add to question body

Comment: Have you checked your solder joints on the header.  Perhaps you have a short circuit.

Comment: That's it. Had a bad solder job on the back off the adafruit causing some pins to touch. Thanks